# Docker Error: standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build docker image for scigraph, the image is getting built successfully but when I try to run I'm getting following error

```
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I am copying already compiled scigraph, and copying the binary version to docker

My Docker file is here

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Set locales
RUN locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE en_GB.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y git build-essential curl wget software-properties-common

#Reference 2:http://help.jabref.org/en/Installation
RUN \
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer wget unzip tar && \
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.5.2

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

VOLUME /root/.m2

RUN ["mvn", "-version"]

ADD ./SciGraph /usr/share/SciGraph
WORKDIR /usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services
RUN pwd
RUN cat run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

When I run docker inspect on the image built, I got below result

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:335ca1855f158838ec48b04e50b5f9a5d9160549ff70909fdfe1128917158775",
        "RepoTags": [
            "terminology-server:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:7444c6c6a2443b1602e3ae69786658d90f7c23124245b2e935b41e8bce9356c6",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2018-03-16T06:06:24.834821577Z",
        "Container": "e1e8e7a22b8c492aa9ad03b066f8b96a587c3e3b8ffa95999eb9ed9779f67b73",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "e1e8e7a22b8c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8",
                "LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle",
                "MAVEN_VERSION=3.5.2",
                "MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENTRYPOINT [\"./run.sh\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:7444c6c6a2443b1602e3ae69786658d90f7c23124245b2e935b41e8bce9356c6",
            "Volumes": {
                "/root/.m2": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "./run.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "17.11.0-ce",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8",
                "LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle",
                "MAVEN_VERSION=3.5.2",
                "MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:7444c6c6a2443b1602e3ae69786658d90f7c23124245b2e935b41e8bce9356c6",
            "Volumes": {
                "/root/.m2": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "./run.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 6006850073,
        "VirtualSize": 6006850073,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "DeviceId": "119",
                "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-135982681-1702cffe2f92ce39cbf75bfcea05a2ee40eadc2f80b962fc210ec27e96e56462",
                "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
            },
            "Name": "devicemapper"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:92fb50b4d953c72eb1d5c045bab47a78f5c02348d8f004f7229a7b8fef16608d",
                "sha256:e95051d9cb9b95bf46df6cf5affab21157019659b3405e9c69f1f4a8376b24e7",
                "sha256:3abb69fb15dc83c0bf7a562f7bda73844fd20ed8cc4aec7b28ebd4113797cd9a",
                "sha256:dd420adea0d3f9f9da8500d4a8ec542ae0a32e78de557c9ce3755bd416431b5a",
                "sha256:65262d4f5516e81457c1ad5e14da8fbf66a999557107bbc7c2a635cbf94e64d9",
                "sha256:03e3aec56bc75b44ee8325903551663804e6796168a21393ca59acc95585f7fb",
                "sha256:3053ff98dd241a19da60a0dcfb17ddae6295ec8f0f1eb5f12cb3c30a38f8bc51",
                "sha256:9f4d23d434f7f98108c72aa95685641bf9174892afd5a5b381ab44fb9633cbe2",
                "sha256:d2e5c48f386cfb9c9f2a7b617c4b47b57d4f173d5ebdf8cabbb25be376f15e75",
                "sha256:c648b941988def7315a0c2a7c6ef48fcf611d468cab391e2aa3850561c34c806",
                "sha256:cd3923aee93d75b13d1d2e87de5feb671dc3fc81a13899c2c64377c5b997e6ff",
                "sha256:e03445efaadc5bbdb8641ff433afa91d56f5ac54e21b255c679c6bbb1ea1b0c7"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2018-03-16T01:07:03.881388924-05:00"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what is the `ENTRYPOINT` by inspecting your image.

If it is a standard `sh -c`, a `CMD ./run.sh` should be enough.
But if it is not, `./run.sh` might not be compatible with `ENTRYPOINT` command.

---

```
ADD ./SciGraph /usr/share/SciGraph
```

That will copy an executable `SciGraph` to your `Ubuntu` image.
If that executable was not compiled for that Ubuntu 64bits platform, that would generate an "exec format error" at runtime.
That is why [Go crosscompilation](https://golangcookbook.com/chapters/running/cross-compiling/) is important.

Comment: I have updated the question with my docker inspect details, I couldn't figure out the cause.